# What are the most major issues with IE [website development]?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

After being busy sometime with website development and constantly having trouble with making my website work on IE also, i thought it might be handy to have an overview of what the most major issues with IE are, so that one can take care of addressing them from the beginning.
(Should this be a community wiki?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/)